# DJango authenticate function returning wrong?

Tags: django, authentication

Using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in, I've tried to authenticate users on my website. However, the authenticate method always returns a `None` type. I am not sure why because the user does exist in my system and I am typing the password correctly.

In my system, I have it so that the username is the email so that it matches with the login authentication.

Here is the code where I check for validation:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']

        user2 = User.objects.get(username=email)
        print(user2.first_name)
        print(user2.username)

        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(user)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            form.clean()


    else:
        print("form is invalid")
```

In my case, the `form` is valid and user2 DOES exist in the database as I have checked it's email and username and they are all the same. Why is this happening?

EDIT: Some more information. I've created the user by using a signup form. This user is stored in the database as I can see it inside the admin panel. This is what the login form looks like (not using google login)

[image]

Here is the html file incase it is needed:

```
    {% extends "mainapp/base.html" %}
{% load socialaccount %}

{# Loads the css files and pics #}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container col">
    <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input name="{{ form.email.name }}" class="form-control" type="email" required>
            {{ form.email.errors }}
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">

            <label>Password: </label>
            <input name="{{ form.password.name }}" class="form-control" type="password" required>
            {{ form.password.errors }}
        </div>

        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <!-- Sign in button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" value="sign_in">Sign in</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Google sign up button -->
    <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">
        <button class="btn btn-light col-md-12 mt-2">
            <img width="20px" style="margin-bottom:3px; margin-right:5px" alt="Google sign-in"
                 src="{% static 'mainapp/google_logo.png' %}"/>
            Sign in with Google
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: how does your password look in database?

Comment: @iklinac good question, I've let django do that automatically for now. I haven't done anything to the default way it stores passwords.

Comment: so how does it look like, and how did you exactly create password on that user

Comment: @iklinac. I've edited the post!

Comment: show us your signup view

Comment: Try this `user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)`. I know `request` is optional but let give it a try.